# javascript is not enabling within html code, pycharm IDE

Tags: javascript, pycharm

The following is the code :
when I click on R or G or B buttons, colors should be changed, but not happening as expected, what was the wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>BackGround</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="red"> R </button>
  <button id="blue"> B </button>
  <button id="green"> G </button>
  <script>
    let body = document.querySelector('body');
    document.querySelector('#red').oncliclk = function() {
      body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    };
    document.querySelector('#blue').oncliclk = function() {
      body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    };
    document.querySelector('#green').oncliclk = function() {
      body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Should be `onclick`, not `oncliclk`

Answer (score 0):

i think you made some spelling mistakes, not sure tho
also dont put spaces between "="

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>BackGround</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <button id="red"> R </button>
            <button id="blue"> B </button>
            <button id="green"> G </button>
            <script>
                let body = document.querySelector('body');
                document.querySelector('#red').onclick = function(){
                 body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                };
                document.querySelector('#blue').onclick = function(){
                    body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                };
                document.querySelector('#green').onclick = function(){
                    body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                };
                </script>
            </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes problem resolved. Corrected as suggested by above